# OpenCV Optical Flow Zero Velocity Holes

Tags: c++, opencv, opticalflow

I'm using OpenCV CUDA Optical Flow Farneback to compute a flow map but the result frequently contains zero velocity holes. (Please refer to the video link below.)
So I was wondering if this is an artifact that can be removed by optimizing parameters.

[Color Map + Original](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-td5A2a1orI)

[Color Map Only](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LFZqlyUfd8)

The "hole" mentioned above. Inside the purple boundaries, the black region has zero velocity. [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWhZr.jpg)

The Farneback parameters are as following.

```
const int numLevels = 4;
const float pyrScale = 0.5;
const bool fastPyramids = true;
const int winSize = 11;
const int numIters = 10;
const int polyN = 7; // 5 or 7
const float polySigma = 2.4;
```

Then the x,y components are converted in HSV format.

Please let me know if you need additional information.